# Can't pass a function to a component via <Route />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

**setErm** is a function and is undefined in **Erm** component. Although the **App** component receives it. If I pass anything like `something='foo'` the ERM component get's it but not `setErm={props.setErm}`

```
const App = props => {
  console.log("props in App", props);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route
            path="/erm"
            render={props => <Erm {...props} setErm={props.setErm} />}
          />
          <Route exact path="/:weekId" component={Week} />
          <Route exact path="/:weekId/:dayId" component={Day} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that in your **Erm** component **props** here refer to the **Route** component **props** not **App** props so you can change your code to use the props of App to something like this:

```
const App = props => {
  console.log('props in App', props);
  const appProps = props; // add this line to refer to App props
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route
            path="/erm"
            render={props => <Erm {...props} setErm={appProps.setErm} />}
          />
          <Route exact path="/:weekId" component={Week} />
          <Route exact path="/:weekId/:dayId" component={Day} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Or you can use destructuring:

```
const App = ({ setErm }) => {
  console.log('props in App', props);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route
            path="/erm"
            render={props => <Erm {...props} setErm={setErm} />}
          />
          <Route exact path="/:weekId" component={Week} />
          <Route exact path="/:weekId/:dayId" component={Day} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

As you can see you now able to use the top props of App component

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks